# SonarLint Eclipse - Analyze all?

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube, sonarlint

I've got Eclipse Neon (4.6.0) with SonarLint 2.3.1. It's connected to my server and shows me the problems in each file quite fine. But unfortunately, it **only** does so when opening a file. As long as a file is not opened, SonarLint doesn't notice any problems, so I cannot get an overview about all my problems in my projects (except by opening all files manually).

The [SonarLint FAQ](http://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/#FAQ) says to click "Analyze", but unfortunately, in the SonarLint sub menu, I can only choose to unbind my project or change the binding, no "Analyze" there...

Anyone got an idea how to get SonarLint to run a full analysis over my projects?